# android error handling, assertions or exception handling

Tags: java, android, exception, assert

I generally use exception handling to gracefully throw an exception and handle it without having an application crash.

I inherited some code that uses assertions everywhere, and the app crashes a lot in debugging, everytime the assertions fail, with assertionfailed error.

A lot of times, these assertions are checking if something is not null, and if it is null it crashes with assertion failed.

This seems entirely counterproductive compared to doing `if(var!=null)` but am I missing something? Am I missing something novel about this code design paradigm?

My current assertion is that all `assert` calls should be commented out and any problem errors should check for null variables instead

I wrote this hoping there is an actual answer to this question, thanks!

Comment: assertions are used, when you are sure some about conditions are rare to happen in production environment. so a 'null' check is the worst use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An assertion is something that REALLY NEVER should happen. assertions are not for checking condition, but to check strong assumption, that you are sure would never gonna happen. when You use assertion, you enable them for debugging, but it should never be in production code.

So, using assertion for null check are the worst idea because in java, null values are all around. better use `if(object == null)`.